# iOS SoundCloud SDK - Unrecognized Selector

Tags: ios, soundcloud

Getting this error after installing Soundcloud SDK via Cocoapods:
+[SCSoundCloud shared]: unrecognized selector sent to class

A couple of things:
After installing the dependencies via cocoapods, my project was unable to find all the headers.  Tried changing header search to project directory, still no dice.

Manually copied over Soundcloud API resources from Pod workspace over to my project workspace, still getting error.

Help?

Comment: Did you definitely open the .workspace file after installing from Cocoapods?

Comment: Yup.  Opened it in Terminal.  Re-set it up again and out of the box I'm getting that same error.

Comment: For some reason, I had to manually set the config file. Works.